# SSRS authentication from the "new" Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, ssrs-2016

For the last 3-4 weeks now, when I login to our SSRS from home, I have to re-enter my credentials no less than 15 times (this is NOT an exaggeration) before I can use the site. Internally, it never asked for credentials until this time.

On the server, I'm running Server 2016 with all of the latest patches and SQL/SSRS 2016 (13.0.5820.21). On my home workstation, I'm running Windows 10 Home Edition. On my desktop at work, I'm running Windows 10 Pro attached to the domain. I remote into my workstation for development work and do everything else locally on my PC at home.

I'm wondering if there was a recent Windows 10 update that may have mangled this up? I'm not hearing complaints from my users and I know general user workstations are significantly delayed for receiving Windows updates.

Any assistance with this horrible bug is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like issue is more related with the SSRS. For testing purposes, try to add this site to the trusted zone. Again try to specify the credentials in your SSRS configuration. Maybe it got changed to prompt the credentials. Try to use TCP instead of HTTPS if possible for you.

Comment: I'm using the new Edge which doesn't have anything to do with trusted zones. The problem is with our external, secured URL. That is giving me the most problems.

Comment: How would I use TCP instead of HTTPS in the browser?

Comment: You need to configure it in your SSRS settings.

Comment: I decided to try the old IE to see if it had the same problem and it does not. So, the problem is NOT on SSRS but in some change to the Chromium engine since this behavior is the same on Edge AND Chrome.